# Cannot find packages installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8 and python 2.7.3. I'm trying to use pip to install ipython, and running sudo pip install ipython installs successfully, but when I try to run ipython I get "command not found". I cannot find where pip installs packages, or why it's not linking correctly. I'm very new with this, please help!

Comment: What do you get if you type `locate ipython`?

Comment: Have you tried restarting terminal?

Comment: Aha! locate ipython finds it in /usr/local/share/python/, and now I can just add that to my path. Thank you very much! I spent much too long trying to google this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, on an OS X 10.5, the default installation of Python is soft-linked to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/`, and ipython is at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython`.  Make sure the `bin` directory it's sitting in is in your shell `PATH`.  Type:

`$ export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH`

, then try running ipython.  If that works, edit your `~/.profile` to update your `PATH` permanently.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and fixed it by restarting my terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by using sudo. sudo will install the ipython in system folder.

pip uninstall ipython

and than

sudo pip install ipython

Answer (score 0):

Similar to acjay, for me worked with:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

adding to path (10.12 Sierra).